# Firebase update list values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is datastructure:

```
 categories
      0 : category1,
      1 : category2,
      2 : category3
```

I want to **concurrently** add values to this structure.
It looks like updateChildren() method will replace list with a new one.

```
     Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

What is the best practise to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by stressing concurrently?  You just mean you want to update the names of individual categories without having to update all of them at the same time?

Comment: @BooberBunz idk, but I'm sure he's mixed up data structure.

Comment: @BooberBunz several  users may add or remove item to this data structure.

Comment: @dmreshet Did I help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's bad practice. (*To find out why, look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data)*)and . Instead of using `0:`,`1:`, etc, use the Firebase `push()` method. Which generates a unique key like `-K9929EDDJDODAK939`. Your structure will look like this:

```
categories:
   -K9929EFDADFAK939: category 1,
   -DFADF9ADFFDF: category 2,
    K99DF9EDDJDO9: category 3
```

To this, use the `push()` method when saving those into the database, like this:

```
ref.child("categories").push().setValue(valueOrHasMap);
```

You don't need to use `updateChildren()`, just save them like I mentioned. It will keep on saving and won't replace ANY existing.

Fore more information, you should read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data), and especially how to [**retrieve** data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) when using this method.

For more information on avoiding Arrays in Firebase: (Thanks for @Wiliks for the link) [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: leaving a link to an old official blog post on why we should avoid arrays in firebase database [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: @Wilik I will include your link, that you for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data structure so that your 0,1,2,3, etc are INDEXES and not KEYs of a key-value pair... so it would look like:

```
 categories:
      0:
          name:category1,
      1:
          name:category2,
      2:
          name:category3
```

Comment: did i misunderstand your question?

Comment: @AbAppletic Your answer is essentially the same.  My point was indexed vs. not indexed.  I never said the indexes would literally need to be called "0" "1" or "2"

Comment: Indeed, but non-advanced users will consider it that way.

Comment: And my answer explains **much** more clearly than you explained yours.